# Arduino Mega and RAMPS 1.4 not responding

Tags: arduino-mega-2650

I was working on upgrading my Anet A8 to a RAMPS 1.4 running on Marlin. I had everything ready to go and had plugged it in to see if it worked. It seemed to be working so I tried to home it and my y end stop was not on. The printer ground for a second and before I could stop it the whole thing shut off. Now it won’t seem to turn back on. I had originally though it was an issue with the power supply, as I plugged it into my computer and it worked fine. But now when I plug it into my computer the backlight comes on and it shuts off. On the Arduino Mega the only lights that come on are two red ones. Does anyone have any idea what may have caused this?

Comment: Does the Arduino Mega still work? Remove the RAMPS entirely then try uploading something like the blink script and see whether the onboard LED will blink or not. Try with USB power first, then connect the RAMPS and try with power from the power supply. It could be a burnt power regulator. The onboard regulator can only handle the power draw of the RAMPS itself and all the sensors, but it cannot handle the additional power draw of the LCD. You should add a switching (aka buck) converter to your setup if you want to use the LCD.

Comment: Ok I’ll try that. If that is the case and the power regulator is fried is there a way to replace it or is the board shot?

Comment: You can try to desolder the old one and solder on a new one, but it is going to be hard since it's an SMD package. If it is broken that only means you can't power the Arduino with anything other than 5v. The component you want to look for is "AMs1117-5.0" The better solution is to use a buck converter as I told you, because if you replace the regulator and continue using it in your current setup then it will eventually break again. Meanwhile you can power the Arduino via USB and everything else via the power supply and the printer should work that way.

Comment: The board is just shot. Ill have to buy a new one. Thanks for the help though! I really appreciate it. I'm newer to the arduino side of it. If you know of a tutorial on how to make all of it work is id really appreciate it if you could share it with me.

Comment: It's going to be much better to just buy a new board. Soldering SMD components isn't rocket science, but it requires a bit of experience and helps to have reasonable tools (like a hot air rework station).

Comment: That’s my plan. I’m just having trouble finding a good source for the actual upgrade. Do you have any you recommend?